# Access IIF expression convert to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I inherited an Access query with the following IIF statement which I am trying to convert into a SQL Where condition.  I have played with this for a couple of days cannot get it to return the same results.  Any help would be appreciated.

Access

```
WHERE (((IIf([EFFDATE]-[MATDATE]<>[PDU_DAYS]-1 And [Calc_Type]="Cycles",IIf([PDU_DAYS] Between [30DayDQMin]+1 And [89DayDQMax]+1,"Yes","No"),IIf([PDU_DAYS] Between 31 And 90,"Yes","No")))="Yes"));
```

For the SQL code I have been playing around with various Boolean statements such as the following.  I have also tried building some case logic.  No luck so far.

```
([EffDATE]-[MatDate] <> [PDU_Days]-1 and CalcType = 'Cycles' and PDU_Days Between [30DayDQMin]+1 and [89DayDQMax]+1 or PDU_Days Between 31 and 90)
```

Comment: What are the datatypes of those fields?

Answer (score 0):

You should succeed using several CASE WHEN x THEN a ELSE b END instructions as follows :

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN (([EFFDATE]-[MATDATE]<>[PDU_DAYS]-1) And ([Calc_Type]='Cycles')) THEN
    CASE WHEN (([PDU_DAYS] Between [30DayDQMin]+1) And ([89DayDQMax]+1))
        THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
ELSE 
     CASE WHEN ([PDU_DAYS] Between 31 And 90) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
END 

= 'Yes'
```

Mind the T-SQL single quote style !

Answer (score 0):

Here is equivalent SQL-Server Syntax :

```
(
    CASE WHEN ([EFFDATE]-[MATDATE] <> [PDU_DAYS]-1 AND [Calc_Type]= 'Cycles') THEN
        CASE WHEN ([PDU_DAYS] BETWEEN [30DayDQMin]+1 AND [89DayDQMax]+1) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN [PDU_DAYS] BETWEEN 31 AND 90 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    END
) = 'yes'
```

and if `[MATDATE]` and `[EFFDATE]` are `datetime` fields then :

```
(
    CASE WHEN (DATEDIFF(dd,[MATDATE],[EFFDATE]) <> [PDU_DAYS]-1 AND [Calc_Type]= 'Cycles') THEN
        CASE WHEN ([PDU_DAYS] BETWEEN [30DayDQMin]+1 AND [89DayDQMax]+1) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN [PDU_DAYS] BETWEEN 31 AND 90 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
    END
) = 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need all that conditional convolutedness, this should yield the same result:

```
WHERE ([EFFDATE]-[MATDATE]<>[PDU_DAYS]-1 
       AND [Calc_Type]="Cycles" 
       AND ([PDU_DAYS] BETWEEN [30DayDQMin]+1 AND [89DayDQMax]+1)
      )
      OR ([PDU_DAYS] Between 31 And 90)
```